# AnyDesk Remote Computer Resolution Stuck

Tags: display-resolution, anydesk

Using AnyDesk to connect from my laptop to my PC, since the remote screen was to small I used auto adapt, the next time I restarted my PC the resolution shrunk to 1280x1024 and was orignally 1980x1080 and now the edges of my screen are black. I tried multiple solutions that didn't work and it says that this is the min, max resolution possible. The display also no longer uses the entire screen. Please Help! Using Ubuntu 20.04 and the latest version of Anydesk

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that AnyDesk seems to have changed the kernel and now Ubuntu cannot recognize my monitor. I couldn't find the xorg.config file and where it changed the kernel. Gave up and a fresh reinstall of Ubuntu fixed it.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to edit this answer, so I left the last sentence unchanged. Did you give up and reinstall Ubuntu?